# How to paginate blog post in Slim 2?

Tags: php, slim

I am trying to paginate blog posts with Slim 2 Framework, but I am confused in how to pass parameters in rest frameworks.

How can we attend `localhost/blog.php?page=2` in Slim 2?

Comment: It's probably easier (and cleaner) to use the routing system, e.g. `/blog/2`. This is explained in [the documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/get/). Do you need the `blog.php` or the `?page=` URL stuff?

Comment: can we attend url of something like that blog/?page=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use URLs like `localhost/blog.php?page=2` in Slim, but it defeats the purpose of the routing system. The ideal approach is to route using routing entirely, such as `/blog/2`.

However, you can also do it your way. Set up a route for `/blog` and then read `$_GET['page']` inside the controller function. Don't forget to cast it to `int`, so the input is safe. Always check for parameter presence too, with `isset()`, to prevent non-existent index notices.

---

By the way, I noticed a problem with this code:

```
$page = $request->get('page');

// Get the current page if not set to page 1
$currentPage = isset($page) ? $page : 1;
if(!is_numeric($currentPage)) {
    $app->notFound();
}
```

You've used `isset()` here, which won't help -- `$page` will *always* be set after the first line. This would be appropriate for checking whether an entry exists in the `$_GET` superglobal, but we're not using that here.

Also, it's better to add a condition to a routing parameter than to check it is a number manually. Rolling all that together, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/blog(/:page)', function() use ($app) {
    $page = $request->get('page');
    $maxPage = 4; // This would be done dynamically
    if ($page < 1 || $page >  $maxPage) {
        $app->notFound();
    }

    // More code here...
})->conditions(array('page' => '\d+'));
```

Comment: Please see the code [http://codepad.org/RjqKO0T7](http://codepad.org/RjqKO0T7)..It's working..i wanted to know if the code is ok or can we make it better!